# Yum not installing certain packages on CentOS 7

Tags: python, yum, openerp-7, centos7

I have been trying to solve this problem, but no luck.

I am trying to install OpenERP 7.0 on CentOS 7. I am following this [link](http://eappsetup.com/openerp-7-installation-on-centos-6-4/)

I am unable to install python required packages. When i gave the python installation packages i.e.

```
yum -y install python-psycopg2 python-lxml PyXML python-setuptools libxslt-python pytz \
python-matplotlib python-babel python-mako python-dateutil python-psycopg2 \
pychart pydot python-reportlab python-devel python-imaging python-vobject \
hippo-canvas-python mx python-gdata python-ldap python-openid \
python-werkzeug python-vatnumber pygtk2 glade3 pydot python-dateutil \
python-matplotlib pygtk2 glade3 pydot python-dateutil python-matplotlib \
python python-devel python-psutil python-docutils make\
automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel byacc flashplugin-nonfree poppler-utils pywebdav\
```

it is give error like.

```
Error: Package: hippo-canvas-python-0.3.0-6.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: python-vatnumber-1.0-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: python-openid-2.2.5-7.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: pywebdav-0.9.4.1-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: python-gdata-2.0.11-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: python-psutil-0.6.1-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: mx-3.1.1-6.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: python-psutil-0.6.1-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: mx-3.1.1-6.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: pydot-1.0.3-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
Error: Package: python-vobject-0.8.1c-5.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i save etc/yum.conf file there was no exclude= line to comment, but i found this line `installonly_limit=5` is it an issue?

Postgres SQL is downloadinf files but it is not installing

```
 yum -y install postgresql92-libs postgresql92-server postgresql92
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                                                                                             | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                             | 4.6 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                                                                             | 4.4 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                                                           | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                                                                          | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
(1/6): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                    | 157 kB  00:00:00
(2/6): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                |  26 kB  00:00:01
(3/6): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                      | 250 kB  00:00:02
(4/6): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                               | 3.6 MB  00:00:12
(5/6): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                  | 4.9 MB  00:00:26
(6/6): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                    | 3.3 MB  00:00:29
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                                                    |  59 kB  00:00:00
(2/2): epel/x86_64/pkgtags                                                                                                                       | 1.3 MB  00:00:03
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.vodien.com
 * epel: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * extras: mirror.vodien.com
 * updates: mirror.vodien.com
No package postgresql92-libs available.
No package postgresql92-server available.
No package postgresql92 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

or is there any other method to follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That guide is written for CentOS 6.x and it suggests to install yum repositories made for CentOS 6. This will not work with CentOS 7. Either search for an updated guide or try installing the dependencies only from CentOS 7 [compatible](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) [repositories](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_packages_and_versions_are_available_in_EPEL.3F).